# Problema na inicialização do jogo

Tags: c, allegro

Estou tentando rodar um jogo que fiz no Allegro 4, a aplicação só roda normalmente na primeiro compilação/execução. Se eu fechar o DevC++ e abrir novamente ou tentar executar o arquivo .exe gerado, o jogo para de funcionar.

Após a compilação o jogo abre, porem fica minimizado e travado na barra de tarefas,a única forma de fecha-lo é através do gerenciador de tarefas.

Notei que esse problema apareceu após adicionar som ao jogo.

**Informações:**

Sistema:Windows 7 Professional

IDE:DevC++ 4.9.9.3 (So estou usando o DevC++ pois estou seguindo um tutorial do YouTube)

Biblioteca:Allegro 4.1

**Segue abaixo o código:**

```
#include <allegro.h>

int main(){

// Inicialização
allegro_init();
install_keyboard();
set_color_depth(32);
set_window_title("The Emoji 2");
install_sound(DIGI_AUTODETECT,MIDI_AUTODETECT,NULL);
set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED,800,600,0,0);


// Variáveis
int x = 100;
int y = 100;

// Imagens
BITMAP *buffer = create_bitmap(800,600);
BITMAP *imagem1 = load_bitmap("Emoji1.bmp",NULL);
BITMAP *imagem2 = load_bitmap("Emoji2.bmp",NULL);
BITMAP *face = load_bitmap("Emoji1.bmp",NULL);

// Sons
MIDI *midi = load_midi("midi.mid"); 

play_midi(midi,TRUE); 

while(!key[KEY_ESC]){
    if(key[KEY_RIGHT]){
        x += 1;
        face = imagem2;
    }   
    else if(key[KEY_LEFT]){
        x -= 1;
        face = imagem1;
    }   
    else if(key[KEY_UP]){
        y -= 1;
    }
    else if(key[KEY_DOWN]){
        y += 1;
    }
    draw_sprite(buffer,face, 100 + x, 100 + y);
    draw_sprite(screen,buffer, 0, 0);
    rest(5);
    clear(buffer);  
} // fim do while

destroy_bitmap(buffer);
destroy_bitmap(face);
destroy_bitmap(imagem1);
destroy_bitmap(imagem2);
destroy_midi(midi);
return 0;

} 
END_OF_MAIN()
```

**Obs: Os arquivos chamados no codigo ja ficam dentro da pasta do projeto.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primeira coisa a verificar é se os arquivos `Emoji1.bmp`, `Emoji2.bmp` e `midi.mid` estão presentes na mesma pasta que o executável está.

Para se proteger contra problemas de os recursos (imagens e música) não puderem ser carregados, seria verificando os ponteiros retornados. Por exemplo:

```
BITMAP *imagem1 = load_bitmap("Emoji1.bmp", NULL);
if (imagem1 == NULL) {
    printf("Não conseguiu abrir o arquivo Emoji1.bmp");
    goto fim;
}
BITMAP *imagem2 = load_bitmap("Emoji2.bmp", NULL);
if (imagem2 == NULL) {
    printf("Não conseguiu abrir o arquivo Emoji2.bmp");
    goto fim;
}
```

```
MIDI *midi = load_midi("midi.mid");
if (midi == NULL) {
    printf("Não conseguiu abrir o arquivo midi.mid");
    goto fim;
}
```

O *label* `fim`, você coloca antes do `destroy_bitmap(buffer);`. No entanto, para evitar um erro de compilação, você primeiro vai ter que declarar os bitmaps e o mid e atribuir-lhes `NULL` antes do primeiro `goto`. Há formas de fazer isso sem usar esse `goto`, mas fica razoavelmente complicado.

Também existe um *memory leak* aqui. Observe que o `Emoji1.bmp` é aberto duas vezes e uma das referências é a variável `face`.

Você carrega `face` assim:

```
BITMAP *face = load_bitmap("Emoji1.bmp",NULL);
```

E depois, dependendo das teclas pressionadas, faz isso:

```
face = imagem2;
```

Isso vai fazer com que o bitmap carregado originalmente fique perdido na memória.

O certo seria você inicializar `face` assim:

```
BITMAP *face = imagem1;
```

E então, você pode retirar essa linha:

```
destroy_bitmap(face);
```

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
#include <allegro.h>

int main() {

    // Inicialização
    allegro_init();
    install_keyboard();
    set_color_depth(32);
    set_window_title("The Emoji 2");
    install_sound(DIGI_AUTODETECT, MIDI_AUTODETECT, NULL);
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 800, 600, 0, 0);

    // Variáveis
    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;
    MIDI *mid = NULL;
    BITMAP *buffer = NULL;
    BITMAP *imagem1 = NULL;
    BITMAP *imagem2 = NULL;

    // Imagens       
    buffer = create_bitmap(800, 600);
    imagem1 = load_bitmap("Emoji1.bmp", NULL);
    if (imagem1 == NULL) {
        printf("Não conseguiu abrir o arquivo Emoji1.bmp");
        goto fim;
    }
    imagem2 = load_bitmap("Emoji2.bmp", NULL);
    if (imagem2 == NULL) {
        printf("Não conseguiu abrir o arquivo Emoji2.bmp");
        goto fim;
    }
    BITMAP *face = imagem1;

    // Sons
    midi = load_midi("midi.mid"); 
    if (midi == NULL) {
        printf("Não conseguiu abrir o arquivo midi.mid");
        goto fim;
    }

    play_midi(midi, TRUE); 

    while (!key[KEY_ESC]) {
        if (key[KEY_RIGHT]) {
            x++;
            face = imagem2;
        } else if (key[KEY_LEFT]) {
            x--;
            face = imagem1;
        } else if (key[KEY_UP]) {
            y--;
        } else if (key[KEY_DOWN]) {
            y++;
        }
        draw_sprite(buffer, face, 100 + x, 100 + y);
        draw_sprite(screen, buffer, 0, 0);
        rest(5);
        clear(buffer);
    } // fim do while

    fim:
    destroy_bitmap(buffer);
    destroy_bitmap(imagem1);
    destroy_bitmap(imagem2);
    destroy_midi(midi);
    return 0;
}
END_OF_MAIN()
```

No mais, o Allegro 4 está morto. Agora todo o desenvolvimento segue com o Allegro 5. o Dev-C++ também é um dinossauro.

Comment: Muito obg pela ajuda Victor. Apos colocar a verificação de arquivos no codigo, percebi que o jogo por algum motivo nao consegue carregar as imagens, vc sabe mais ou menos o que poderia ser ? Os arquivos ja estao na pasta.

Comment: Alem disso, quando o codigo da um salto com o goto, o compilador emite tres mensagens e o programa falha. As mensagens sao:"crosses inicialization of MIDI *midi",crosses inicialization of BITMAP *face e "crosses inicialization of BITMAP *imagem2"

Comment: @Rogi93 Resposta editada.